# Tensorflowjs: does loadFrozenModel mean i cannot acess layers?

Tags: tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

used to load model by calling `tf.loadModel('https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/tfjs/mobilenet_v1_0.25_128/model.json')`, however, i needed to change the mobilinet version.

So, i took the version i needed from tensorflowhub, ran it on tensorflow_converter, and got the two files (.pb and the weight file). Then i loaded it using tf.loadGraphModel. hower, model.getLayer throws:

> model.getLayer is not a function.

the loading looks like this:

```
const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(modelUrl); //url points to .pb
```

Then i saved the mobilinet model as a frozen model, ran it again on tensorflow_converter, and tried to load it as tf.loadFrozenModel. which returned the same thing.

im confused.

Is there a way to get layers from a non-keras model?

EDIT: for clarification, the model i took from tensoflowhub is : 
https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_075_96/classification/2

Answer (score 1):

`LoadFrozenModel` is deprecated since 0.15. `LoadGraphModel` does the same thing with less parameter. It takes only as parameter the model topology file.

If there is no layers in the object loaded, it is either because the model is not well loaded or the frozen model does not contain any .

Comment: i see, thank you. But even with graphModel i cannot assess layers?

Comment: Make sure that you're loading correctly the model. A console.log(model) will give you all the properties you can access on the object

Comment: Alright, so log(model) returns: Object { modelUrl: "/static/web_/tensorflowjs_model.pb", weightManifestUrl: "/static/web_/weights_manifest.json", requestOption: undefined, weightPrefix: null, onProgress: undefined, version: "0.0", handler: {…}, executor: {…} }; I can see that functions like getLayer are missing, but im not sure if it means that i loaded it badly or what does it mean?

Comment: Are you loading the model using a local server ?

Comment: I am using flask, so at least in theory i hope i should be able to do so, no? Though i just tried using a regular link to github ("https://rawcdn.githack.com/randomarchive101/test/0cba9c7d5f134ed01b1f7a507ff94e6f7f7bef93/tensorflowjs_model.pb") and it loads the same exact object?

Answer (score 1):

TF.js supports two APIs and corresponding serialization formats: the Layers API (corresponding to Keras models) and the lower-level Core API (corresponding to arbitrary TensorFlow graphs).

Depending on where you obtain a model and how you convert it, your file can be loaded either via `tf.loadLayersModel()` or `tf.loadGraphModel()`, but not both.  Please see the [table of available conversions](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter#format-conversion-support-tables).

Even if a model was originally trained using Keras, it may have been saved as a low-level TensorFlow graph where the Keras layers structure is lost.  I believe this is currently the case for all TF-Hub modules.  Thus your current approach gives you a `tf.GraphModel`, from which the layers cannot be reconstituted.

We provide MobileNet v1 already converted from the original Keras to the TF.js Layers format at the URL you listed, so you can use `loadLayersModel()` (formerly `loadModel()`) with that directly.  We don't currently host a converted MobileNet v2.  However you can get the original Keras .h5 model [here](https://github.com/JonathanCMitchell/mobilenet_v2_keras/releases), and then convert that to TF.js Layers format using `tensorflowjs_converter`.